# Rails syntax for comments in templates: is this bug understood?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, comments, partials

Using rails 2.3.2 I have a partial _foo.rhtml that begins with a comment
as follows:

```
<% # here is a comment %>
<li><%= foo %></li>
```

When I render the partial from a view in the traditional way, e.g.

```
<% some_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] %>
<ul>
<%= render :partial => "foo", :collection => some_numbers %>
</ul>
```

I found that the <li> and </li> tags are ommitted in the output -- i.e. the resulting HTML is

```
<ul> 1 2 3 4 5 </ul>
```

However, I can solve this problem by fixing _foo.rhtml to eliminate the space between
the <% and the # so that the partial now reads:

```
<%# here is a comment %>
<li><%= foo %></li>
```

My question: what's going on here?  E.g., is <% # comment %> simply
incorrect syntax for including comments in a template?  Or is the
problem more subtle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done the test myself, but I'm under the impression that the code should be generating this:

```
<ul> 1 </li> 2 </li> 3 </li> 4 </li> 5 </li> </ul>
```

Which is invalid HTML. Firefox has a tendency of discarding it before showing it to firebug. Are you browsing the generated code through firebug? If yes, I recommend you to "View / Source Code", just to see that the generated code is the same.

My understanding of what happens here is that the `#` with the space before it "comments out" the `%>` bit, so you are in effect "still inside ruby" on the next line. It should have given a weird error at that point, though. But it doesn't, so somehow this is accepted as valid ruby code:

```
<li><%= foo %>
```

I don't know how this could possibly return the value of foo :/.

The `%>` that appears on that line is actually the one closing the `<%` on line one. If I'm correct, then the `</li>` should also be generated.

If this is not the case, then I'm talking nonsense, so apologies.

Comment: You are absolutely right -- firebug reported no </li> tags, but checking the source code revealed them exactly as you predicted.

Comment: BTW, others confirmed your answer here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/202330

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That is a strange bug, but `<%#` is the valid comment syntax (without the spaces). It is the same with the other options:

1. `<%=` print the output
2. `<%-` don't put a line break before this block
3. `<%#` ignore this block

None of them should have spaces between the `<%` and the additional character.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact thing yesterday when I tried bootstrapping the code for a new client's project.  Interesting thing is that it's happening on 1.8.7 but not on a couple machines that are running 1.8.6.  What version of Ruby are you running?